# printing on the same line in python

Tags: python-2.7, terminal

I have a basic code that just simply loops over and print some numbers in python. My problem was that I needed a different way to print my output since I wanted them to be on the same line. (The standard python print statement just prints stuffs on a new line). After doing some research i discovered that I could do something like this

```
    import random
from sys import stdout
    i= 0
    while i < 100:
        j = 0
        while j < 4:
            k =0
            while k < 4:
                sys.stdout.write(random.randint(0, 9))
                k += 1
            sys.stdout.write(" ") 
            j += 1   
        i += 1
        print "\n"
```

This works like charm when I run it using IDLE -- python's ide, my only problem is that whenever I try to run it from the terminal it complains about this

```
    CallingCard $ python numGenerator.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numGenerator.py", line 13, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(random.randint(0, 9))
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
CallingCard $
```

Wondering what might be the problem since running it from IDLE, FYI I am using python 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Deep thinking helps sometimes
Below is the code

```
    i= 0
while i < 100:
    j = 0
    while j < 4:
        k =0
        while k < 4:
            sys.stdout.write("%s" % random.randint(0, 9))
            k += 1  
        sys.stdout.write(" ") 
        j += 1   
    i += 1
    print "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the sys module instead of just the stdout object, because you refer to it from the sys name:

```
import sys
```

Otherwise you would have to modify you call like:

```
stdout.write("foo")
```

Or just use a print command with a comma to supress a newline.

```
print "foo",
```

Comment: actually I know print works but I was looking for a way to print on the same line. I tried import sys and that did not work either

Comment: I just told you though. Put a comma at the end and it prints on one line

Comment: The one catch with using `print "foo",` (trailing comma) is that a blank space is added between each of the printed values.

Comment: True. Good thing I mentioned fixing the import for sys as the first option.

Answer (score 0):

If you did intend to print a 100 lines of four 4-digit numbers per line, you could use

```
from sys import stdout
....
stdout.write(str(random.randint(0, 9)))
```

Although you could really still use print and make it neater with something like

```
import random
from sys import stdout
i= 0
while i < 100:
    for j in range(4):
        print '%04d' % random.randint(0,10000),
   i += 1
   print "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    
    for i in range(n):
        i =i +1
        print(i, end="", sep = '')
```

#printing the number on a single line with no whitespacing.